# Не отображаются данные в TableView javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

С помощью **Scene Builder** создал интерфейс окна с ***TableView***. Для контроллера заимплементил интерфейс ***Initializable***. Переопределил метод ***initialize***:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
tcIdPerson.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idPerson"));
tcNamePerson.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("namePerson"));
tcDateOfBirth.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateOfBirth"));
tcWeightPerson.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("weightPerson"));
tcProgram.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("program"));

Person p1 = new Person(1, "Ivan", "19.01.2001", 78, "k1");
Person p2 = new Person(2, "Ivan", "01.03.2001", 79, "LK");
Person p3 = new Person(3, "Ivan", "23.10.2001", 74, "GJ");
Person p4 = new Person(4, "Ivan", "25.11.2001", 77, "GG");
personData.addAll(p1, p2, p3, p4);
tvPersons.setItems(personData);

}
```

Класс Person:

```
public class Person {
private SimpleIntegerProperty idPerson;
private SimpleStringProperty namePerson;
private SimpleStringProperty dateOfBirth;
private SimpleDoubleProperty weightPerson;
private SimpleStringProperty program;

public Person(){}
public Person(int idPerson, String namePerson, String dateOfBirth, double weightPerson, String program) {
    this.idPerson = new SimpleIntegerProperty(idPerson);
    this.namePerson = new SimpleStringProperty(namePerson);
    this.dateOfBirth = new SimpleStringProperty(dateOfBirth);
    this.weightPerson = new SimpleDoubleProperty(weightPerson);
    this.program = new SimpleStringProperty(program);
}
public int getIdPerson() {
    return idPerson.get();
}
public void setIdPerson(int idPerson) {
    this.idPerson = new SimpleIntegerProperty(idPerson);
}
public String getNamePerson() {
    return namePerson.get();
}
public void setNamePerson(String namePerson) {
    this.namePerson = new SimpleStringProperty(namePerson);
}
public String getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth.get();
}
public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = new SimpleStringProperty(dateOfBirth);
}
public double getWeightPerson() {
    return weightPerson.get();
}
public void setWeightPerson(double weightPerson) {
    this.weightPerson = new SimpleDoubleProperty(weightPerson);
}
public String getProgram() {
    return program.get();
}
public void setProgram(String program) {
    this.program = new SimpleStringProperty(program);
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "idPerson=" + idPerson.get() +
            ", namePerson=" + namePerson.get() +
            ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth.get() +
            ", weightPerson=" + weightPerson.get() +
            ", program=" + program.get() +
            '}';
}}
```

Данные в таблице выводятся. Как только получаю данные извне и пытаюсь отобразить в TableView:

```
     public void showTableView(ObservableList<Person> personObservableList) {
         tvPersons = new TableView<>();
         tvPersons.setItems(personObservableList);

     }
```

ничего не происходит. В консоли тоже пусто - никаких ошибок.
Если закомментировать строку `tvPersons = new TableView<>();` получаю NullPointerException.
Код fxml документа:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="780.0" prefWidth="1100.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.sikus.kiksort.controller.MainController">
   <BorderPane prefHeight="780.0" prefWidth="1100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <top>
         <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="10.0" style="-fx-background-color: #eb984e;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <ImageView fitHeight="70.0" fitWidth="70.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
                  <Image url="@../icons/logo.png" />
            </ImageView>
                     <Button fx:id="btnCreateDataBase" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="90.0" text="Новая база" textAlignment="CENTER">
                  <HBox.margin>
                     <Insets />
                  </HBox.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
               </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btnLoadDataBase" layoutX="130.0" layoutY="44.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Загрузить базу" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </HBox.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btnLoadExcel" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonClick" text="Загрузить Excel" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btnAddSportsman" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonClick" text="Добавить участника" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font></Button>
            <BorderPane.margin>
               <Insets />
            </BorderPane.margin>
         </HBox>
      </top>
      <center>
         <TableView fx:id="tvPersons" prefHeight="685.0" prefWidth="888.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
           <columns>
             <TableColumn fx:id="tcIdPerson" maxWidth="70.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="40.0" resizable="false" text="№" />
             <TableColumn fx:id="tcNamePerson" maxWidth="369.0" prefWidth="369.0" text="Ф.И.О" />
               <TableColumn fx:id="tcDateOfBirth" maxWidth="311.0" prefWidth="108.0" text="Дата рождения" />
               <TableColumn fx:id="tcWeightPerson" maxWidth="279.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="Вес (кг)" />
               <TableColumn fx:id="tcProgram" maxWidth="367.0" prefWidth="294.0" text="Вид программы" />
           </columns>
            <opaqueInsets>
               <Insets />
            </opaqueInsets>
         </TableView>
      </center>
      <left>
         <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="5.0" style="-fx-background-color: #82e0aa;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <Label text="Сортировка">
                  <VBox.margin>
                     <Insets />
                  </VBox.margin>
                  <font>
                     <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                  </font>
               </Label>
               <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
               <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
               <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
               <Line endX="100.0" startX="-100.0">
                  <VBox.margin>
                     <Insets />
                  </VBox.margin>
               </Line>
               <Label text="Отчеты">
                  <font>
                     <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                  </font>
                  <VBox.margin>
                     <Insets />
                  </VBox.margin>
               </Label>
               <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="185.0" text="Лоу кик">
                  <VBox.margin>
                     <Insets />
                  </VBox.margin>
               </Button>
               <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="185.0" text="Кик-лайт">
                  <VBox.margin>
                     <Insets />
                  </VBox.margin>
               </Button>
               <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="185.0" text="К-1">
                  <VBox.margin>
                     <Insets />
                  </VBox.margin>
               </Button>
               <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="185.0" text="Button">
                  <VBox.margin>
                     <Insets />
                  </VBox.margin>
               </Button>
               <Line endX="100.0" startX="-100.0">
                  <VBox.margin>
                     <Insets />
                  </VBox.margin>
               </Line>
            </VBox>
      </left>
      <bottom>
         <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <Label text="Приветствую!">
                  <HBox.margin>
                     <Insets left="30.0" />
                  </HBox.margin>
               </Label>
         </HBox>
      </bottom>
   </BorderPane>
 </AnchorPane>
```

Код контроллера с TableView:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private Button btnAddSportsman;

@FXML
private Button btnCreateDataBase;

@FXML
private Button btnLoadDataBase;

@FXML
private Button btnLoadExcel;

@FXML
private TableView<Person> tvPersons; //Таблица

@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> tcDateOfBirth; // Столбцы таблицы

@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> tcIdPerson;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> tcNamePerson;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> tcProgram;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> tcWeightPerson; // Последний столбец таблицы

private final ObservableList<Person> personData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


static Stage someStage;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

tcIdPerson.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idPerson"));
tcNamePerson.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("namePerson"));
tcDateOfBirth.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateOfBirth"));
tcWeightPerson.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("weightPerson"));
tcProgram.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("program"));

Person p1 = new Person(1, "Ivan", "19.01.2001", 78, "k1");
Person p2 = new Person(2, "Ivan", "01.03.2001", 79, "LK");
Person p3 = new Person(3, "Ivan", "23.10.2001", 74, "GJ");
Person p4 = new Person(4, "Ivan", "25.11.2001", 77, "GG");
personData.addAll(p1, p2, p3, p4);
tvPersons.setItems(personData);

}

@FXML
private void handleButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
if (event.getSource() == btnAddSportsman) {
showSaDialog("addPerson");
}
if (event.getSource() == btnLoadExcel) {
showSaDialog("loadExcel");
}

}

public void showTableView(ObservableList<Person> personObservableList) {
tvPersons = new TableView<>();
tvPersons.setItems(personObservableList);

}

//Передаем в метод имя fxml-файла
public void showSaDialog(String fxml) {
try {
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/sikus/kiksort/fxml/" + fxml + ".fxml"));
someStage = new Stage();
Parent parent = loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
someStage.setResizable(false);
someStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
someStage.setTitle("Менеджер соревнований");
Image image = new Image(String.valueOf(getClass().getResource("/com/sikus/kiksort/icons/icon.png")));
someStage.getIcons().add(image);
someStage.setScene(scene);
someStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
someStage.show();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Код контроллера, после закрытия окна которого данные должны опявиться в таблице:

```
public class LoadExcelController {

@FXML
private Button btnChooser;

@FXML
private Button btnOk;

@FXML
private Label lblPathToFile;

private File file;

MainController mainController;

/*****************************************************************************/
/** Обработка нажатия кнопок окна */
@FXML
private void handleButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
if (event.getSource() == btnOk) {
//TODO
ExcelWorker excelWorker = new ExcelWorker();
XSSFWorkbook workbookFromFile = excelWorker.getWorkbookFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
mainController = new MainController();
mainController.showTableView(FXCollections.observableList(excelWorker.getDataFromWorkbook(workbookFromFile)));
MainController.someStage.close();
}
if (event.getSource() == btnChooser) {
locateFile();
//TODO
}
}
/*****************************************************************************/
/** Загружаем выбранный файл */
private void locateFile() {
FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Excel", "*.xlsx"));
chooser.setTitle("Выберите файл");
MainController.someStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
file = chooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
try{
if (file != null) {
lblPathToFile.setText("Файл:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
btnOk.setDisable(false);
} else {
lblPathToFile.setText("Вы не выбрали файл!");
btnOk.setDisable(true);
}
MainController.someStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
lblPathToFile.setText("Ошибочка вышла...");
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Перепробовал все советы, которые только мог найти, ничего не помогло. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Если используете FXML, то в контроллере должно быть поле `@FXML TableView tvPersons;`, соответствующее TableView в файле fxml, ну и у контрола в fxml должно быть прописано имя поля внутри контроллера. `tvPersons = new TableView<>();` создает отдельный контрол, никак не привязанный к окну.

Comment: Есть такое поле. В методе initialize я туда кладу данные и они выводятся. Пробую положить через другой метод и либо NullPointerException на таблице или на каком-то столбце, либо ничего не происходит, если писать new TableView()

Comment: Не нужно перезаписывать tvPersons вручную, оно инициализируется автоматически на основе данных из fxml файла при загрузке контроллера. Если не инициализируется - нужно разбираться почему, но сейчас в вопросе недостаточно данных, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. Как минимум, нужен полный код контроллера и fxml файл.

Comment: То, что инициализация автоматическая, это я понимаю. Не понимаю только, почему не работает. fxml добавил в правке вопроса.

Comment: Код контроллера добавьте тоже

Comment: В методе showTableView точно не нужно перезаписывать значение tvPersons. Если у вас вызове `tvPersons.setItems(personObservableList);` падает с NPE, значит либо у вас tvPersons где-то перезаписывается на null, либо метод showTableView вызывается до инициализации контроллера, либо в personObservableList передается null.

Comment: Кажется, нашел ошибку. Есть второй контроллер, в котором я снова инициализирую вручную контроллер с TableView. А это, совсем другой объект в памяти, соответственно, и поля объекта тоже.
Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Возможно, но без кода трудно что-то сказать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132185/discussion-between-sergei-and-insolor).

Comment: Не вижу смысла. Нужно добавить весь релевантный код в сам вопрос, чтобы проблему можно было воспроизвести. Обсуждение без кода - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Дополнил код контроллеров.